# how to manage 3000+ sound files

Tags: xcodebuild

This is more of a management issue... Anyway
We're currently making quiz-like game which, well includes a LOT of sound files, and it's bogging down xcode. It's so slow that scrolling up and down takes minutes.

Comment: What exactly are you scrolling up and down? It's not clear where the slowdown is happening.

Comment: I doubt this is anything to do with `xcodebuild` and there's a good chance it's nothing to do with Xcode either - you should at least specify what platform you are developing for...

Comment: I apologize for being so vague, im developing this for the iphone. and about the scrolling, scrolling anything on the xcode gui (like scrolling down so you can see the end of the code/file) takes awhile.

anyway, updating the OS helped a bit. im also planning to change the wav file format im currently using to something different. i havent really decided yet. but thanks for the feedbacks. ill see first what works

Answer (score 0):

You could place them outside of the project and only reference them.